# In SketchUp how do I create a solid half sphere/dome? I keep getting a hole in the top

Tags: 3d-modelling, sketchup

I'm not sure if SO is the best site for this question, but I saw some other sketch-up tags...

I've found a bunch of tutorials that show how to draw a sphere. [Here's one](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Half-Sphere-in-SketchUp) for example. However, whenever I try it I get a half sphere with a hole in the top:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**To Clarify:** The half sphere needs to have a radius of 7/32". I noticed that when I use this measurement (and other smaller ones) I get the problem. I tried it without specifying 7/32" and drew a somewhat bigger second circle and it worked:

[image]

How can I get a solid half sphere that has a radius of 7/32"?

Comment: Honestly, I followed that one and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave this for others' reference. I ended up drawing at 4X and then used the scale tool to shrink it down to 25% after the fact. Maybe SU doesn't do so well with smaller sizes.

Comment: Sketchup does not work well at all with small dimensions. I scale up 1000 then back down 0.001, to avoid snapping and missing face issues. I ended up writing a script to do it automatically.